# Can I have multiple jsHint task configured in a single Grunt file?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a grunt file configured for 2 different modules. In a single task i can give multiple sources and it all works fine. 
Now my requirement is to give different options for both the modules say - I want different JsHint rules for both modules and I want both the projects to have separate minified files and a common minified file.

Gruntfile.js ->

jshint: {

```
  ac:{
      options: {

          laxcomma: true, // maybe we should turn this on? Why do we have these 
          curly: true,
          eqeqeq: true,
          immed: true,
          latedef: true,
          onevar: true
      },
      source: {
          src: ['module1/*.js']
      }
  },
  lib:{
      options: {
          laxcomma: true, // maybe we should turn this on? Why do we have these 
          curly: true,
          eqeqeq: true,
          immed: true,
          latedef: true
      },
      source: {
          src: ['module2/*.js']
      }
  }
```

}

I saw some of the stack overflow question, but i could only find Grunt-hub as an option where i need to create 2 separate files and then a grunt hub file. I dont want to do that, please guide me how to proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use targets: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    one: {
      src: ['files/*'],
      options: { /* ... */ }
    },
    two: {
      src: ['files2/*'],
      options: { /* ... */ }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @Kyle.. Thanks for your answer, but the way you told, everytime JsHint will execute for both the modules. I want that also to be selective i.e. based on my command line input i should be able to to run tasks for one particular module. Please guide me how this will be possible with the above approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `grunt jshint:one` and `grunt jshint:two` to run each target selectively.

Comment: Yes, i tried it and it is working..  Thanks for your help. I want to do the same for other tasks also and then need to define Alias using Registertasks, how can I do that?

Comment: I am able to register the task... :) Need to try it for other tasks now, hope it will work the same way.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I keep getting `0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.` When I don't use target, each configuration works by itself. any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your `src` patterns are matching files. Try with `grunt jshint --verbose` to see more information about which files Grunt is matching.